# c# selenium catch timeoutexception

Tags: c#, selenium, google-chrome, exception, try-catch

I have this code :

```
<code>

cNavigate = true;
while (cNavigate)
    {
     try
        {
         CrDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);
         cNavigate = false;
         }
      catch (WebDriverTimeoutException WebTime)
         {
          log.Info("Naviagte time out : "+WebTime.Message);
         }
    }
</code>
```

But it seems than the timeout is not correctly trapped. Could someone help ?

Comment: Catch all exceptions, and see what will get caught. That is, which exception class gets caught. Then you can write that into your source.

Comment: Usually it can be system related. You can probably block the site you are connecting to or put a time like this because the connection is slow.                                                  
`var driver = new ChromeDriver(url, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(180));`

Answer (score 0):

I finally log it :

`2021-12-15 05:26:18,615 INFO  Browse2.Form1 - Other Exception time out : The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:55790/session/802f7027e123d0319fd98ea41e151413/url timed out after 60 seconds. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: Une tâche a été annulée.
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult() à OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<MakeHttpRequest>d__35.MoveNext() --- Fin de la trace de la pile à partir de l'emplacement précédent au niveau duquel l'exception a été levée --- à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) à System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()
à OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)`

seems than the except thrown is not the same as the one's send

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70326176/edit) the question to add more information. Don't post it in the answer box.